# selecting a particular word from a file in shell scripts

Tags: string, shell, grep

I have a text file with this structure:

```
....

"/home/letizia/Documents/SpanishSegmentation/Recordings/segmented/mfc/F001.0.rec"
COGE
LAS
HOJAS
Y
LAS
QUEMAS
TODAS
EN
EL
FUEGO
"/home/letizia/Documents/SpanishSegmentation/Recordings/segmented/mfc/F002.0.rec"
LA
LIGA
DE
PAZ
SE
REUNIO314201
PARA
TRATAR
EL
TEMA
....
```

and I would like to select "F0001.0" and "F0002.0".

I am using:

```
     ID="F"
     if [[ "$LINE" == *Recordings* ]]
     then        
     SEGMENT=`echo $LINE | grep -o $ID.* | cut -d'.' -f1-2`
     fi
```

but it does not work. Where is the mistake?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `while` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    id="F"
    if [[ "$line" =~ /Recordings/ ]]; then

        segment=$(echo $line | grep -o "$id.*" | cut -d '.' -f1-2)
        echo "$segment"
    fi
done < file.txt
```

Results:

```
F001.0
F002.0
```

---

However, a better way would be to use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/Recordings/s#.*/\(F[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\).*#\1#p' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `sed` instead:

```
sed -n 's@^".*/Recordings/.*/\(.*\)"$@\1@p' file.txt
```

A quick walkthrough:

1. `-n`: don't print anything unless specifically requested (by the final `p`).
2. `s@`: substitute the part until the next `@` with the part until the one after that.
3. `^".*/Recordings/.*/\(.*\)"$`: match a line which starts and ends with double-quotes, contains /Recordings/, and eat everything until the last slash.
4. `\1`: replace the matched string with the last part (which we captured in parentheses).

Comment: If you like my answer, you can vote for it and/or accept it as your preferred solution.  Enjoy StackOverflow!